# I am a beginer at programming,I wrote a code which gives perfect output but online judge didn't accepted.Why it's happen?(Codeforces problem 69A. )

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a,b[101],i,j,sum=0;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    for(i=0;i<a;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            scanf("%d",&b[j]);
            sum=sum+b[j];
            }
    }
    if(sum==0) printf("YES\n");
    else printf("NO\n");
    return 0;
}
```

outputs are showed perfectly but online judge didn't accept.
online judge message"wrong answer on test 81".
link of problem"http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/69/A"

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit question and add 1-what the requirement was, 2-the message you got from "online judge" 3-the link on the problem. Else, you question will likely get closed.

Comment: What is the program supposed to do? And even if such "competition" sites require specific limits in execution time, they generally don't care about built times, so please don't use shortcuts in code like one-letter variables or no comments. Good habits are important to get right from the very beginning, don't let the bad habits of so-called "competition" sites get to you.

Answer (score 3):

[The problem](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/69/A) is asking to check if the sum of all vectors is zero.

Sum of vectors is element-wise addition of vectors, not simple summation of all elements.

Your program will fail in, for example, this case:

```
1
1 0 -1
```